# RegEx for conditions in URL rewriting

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I have a link:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/xx-fr/page/some.page
```

and I would like to match it in urlrewrite `if xx!=ma`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show some of your attempts and where you're having trouble. Also, different tools and languages have some variances. You should specify what you're using.

Comment: @DanFego wrong on both counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is somewhat obscure and non-intuitive operation ?!

```
http://localhost:8080/test/((?!ma)..)-fr/page/some.page
```